# I have problem in including pug-bootstrap file inside my pug file. How to include pug-bootstrap inside layout.pug file

Tags: css, node.js, pug

Inside my layout.pug file. I am trying to include pug-bootstrap as follows.

```
include /node_modules/pug-bootstrap/_bootstrap.pug
doctype html
html
  head
    title= title
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')
    link(rel='shortcut icon' href='/images/logo.png' type='image/x-icon')
    link(rel='preconnect' href='https://fonts.googleapis.com')
    link(rel='preconnect' href='https://fonts.gstatic.com' crossorigin='')
    link(href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=IBM+Plex+Sans+Thai+Looped:wght@300&display=swap' rel='stylesheet')

  body
    header 
      nav(class="navbar") 
        ul(class="navbaritemcontainer")
          li(class='navitem algo' ) 
            a(href="/algorithm") Algorithm
          li(class="navitem")
            a(href="/cpp") c++     
          li(class="navitem")
            a(href="/about") AboutUs
          .log_class 
            if currentUser!==undefined 
              li(class="navitem ")
                  a(href="/logout") LogOut (#{currentUser.username})
            else 
              li(class="navitem signup ")
                      a(href="/signup") Sign up 
              li(class="navitem login")
                      a(href="/login") Login         
    block content
    block foot 
      footer 
        ul(class="footer-block")
          li(class="footer-ele") 
            a(href="/about") AboutUs 
          li(class="footer-ele")
            a(href="/SignUp") SignUp  
          li(class="footer-ele")
            a(href="/login") Login  
        p(class='msg') Copyright &copy; CodeKaro With Basics
```

I trying it using copying it to style file. That process work and I get that idea by searching bootstrap. But as we know we are provided with the node package manager.

So, I want to known how to include pug-bootstrap from there inside my layout. pug file . And how to use it inside other pug files inside my views folder.

Answer (score 0):

Replace "include" with "extends" and it should work.

See here:
https://pugjs.org/language/inheritance.html